# ReactJS ref same components in form

Tags: reactjs, components, ref

I'm working on building Multiple Choice Quiz app on ReactJS.
The first thing the user should do is fill up the form with questions and answers and submit (like on Google Forms).

```
<form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  {questions.map((question, i) => (
    <Question key={i}
              ref={q => this.questionComp = q}
              number={i}
              choices={question.choices} />
  ))}

  <Button type="submit" primary fluid>Submit</Button>
</form>
```

In `<Question />` component i have input fields.
How can I get the values of inputs in each of Question component after onSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

In your Question component, you can add functions that return the values you need.

For example:

```
class Question extends React.Component {
    getInputValue() {
        return this.textInput.value;
    }
    render() {
        return ( <input ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} );
    }
}
```

Then just call the getInputValue function from your question component in the handleSubmit function.

Comment: It works just for on Component. I have multiple Question components.  How can I get values from each of them?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it storing them into an array

```
{questions.map((question, i) => (
        <Question key={i}
                  ref={q => this.questionsArray[i] = q}
                  number={i}
                  choices={question.choices}
                  clickAddQuestion={this.addQuestion} />
      ))}
```